# How to prevent android and Ios device display size chnages in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Currently, I have applied the following code to prevent the font size changes in android it is work for font size changes but it is not working for display size changes to (low, medium, high) in some specific device. The UI text is overlapping.

```
public override Resources Resources
{
    get
    {
        Resources res = base.Resources;
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.SetToDefaults();
        res.UpdateConfiguration(config, res.DisplayMetrics);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "display size changes"? Screen resolution scaling? If you don't want the device's font size to affect your app, why not define absolute font sizes instead of using named sizes?

Comment: Yes, he's referring to Screen Resolution Scaling. Typically stock android phones have Settings > Display > Display Size which can be adjusted between small, default large.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DisplayInfo screenSize = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;` to get the size of screen (height, width, density, etc) and manipulates your font sizes according to each device resolution.

For example:

```
switch (height)
            {
                case (640):
                 //fontSize = 1
                case (800):
                 //fontSize = 2
                case (1024):
                 //fontSize = 3
                case (1280):
                 //fontSize = 4
                case (1920):
                 //fontSize = 5
                case (2048):
                 //fontSize = 6
                case (2560):
                 //fontSize = 7
                case (3840):
                 //fontSize = 8
                case (4096):
                 //fontSize = 9
                default:
                 //fontSize = 10
                 break;
            }
```